# Intercept web server request, modify, forward

Tags: header, request, reroute

The idea is simple but i am not quite sure what would be the best way to implement such a feature.

What i basically wish to achieve is that all web requests that come in
to my server are captured and modified. Cookies, headers etc. are all exchanged.
After that i pass on that request to another web server.

Once the other web server replies i pass that information back on to the browser.
I am currently using IIS with ASP.NET but i am open to all suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use IIS 7 in integrated pipeline mode and write a [http handler](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm) then you'll be heading in the right direction.